# TreeForm outputs different results for the same input, Why?

Tags: bugs, trees

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1**

---

First of all, please look at the below inputs and outputs:

```
In[1]:= $a = Array[# Range[#] &, {5}]

Out[1]= {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 8, 12, 16}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}}

In[2]:= $af = Flatten[$a, {{1}, {2}}]

Out[2]= {{1}, {2, 4}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 8, 12, 16}, {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}}

In[3]:= $a === $af

Out[3]= True

In[4]:= FullForm[$a] === FullForm[$af]

Out[4]= True

In[5]:= TreeForm[$a]

Out[5]:=
```

[image]

```
In[6]:= TreeForm[$af]

Out[6]:=
```

[image]

```
In[7]:= TreeForm[$a] === TreeForm[$af]

Out[7]= True
```

Then, I have natural questions:
Why are there the differences between the output of `TreeForm[$a]` and that of `TreeForm[$af]`? What makes these differences? Though Mathematica says "True"s for the checking equalities.

Comment: Post your code as formatted text, not as graphics.

Comment: @MarcoB I corrected it, sorry.

Comment: This is weird - I would say that `TreeForm[Array[ # Range[#] &, {5}]]`, the first one, is clearly wrong.  Also, the output of `TreeForm@Array[Range[#] &, {5}]` is even weirder...

Comment: Okay, so this is a known bug where `TreeForm` will fail on arrays where the sublists are packed.  Compare the output of ``Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ a``
and ``Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ $af ``.  A workaround is to unpack the subarrays, ``TreeForm[$a /. {x_?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> 
    Developer`FromPackedArray[x]}] ``

Comment: @JasonB I was very surprised with your suggestion, `TreeForm@Array[Range[#] &, {5}]`, I got a very big figure...

Comment: @JasonB That second comment looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @JasonB I'm a beginner in Mathematica and not sure what your codes mean... Anyway, here are the result of the execution for your suggestions: `Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ $a = {True, True, True, True, True}` and `Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ $af = {False, False, False, False, False}`

Comment: @JasonB Regarding above results for your suggesting commands, the sublists are packed in "a" whereas not packed in
"af". Then, TreeForm doesn't work well when it acts to arrays where the sublists are packed, right?

Comment: @TaikiBessho - that is correct.  I give a workaround function below that should suit your needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference between your two examples is that one uses [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/9490) and the other doesn't.  The lists generated by `Range` are, by default, packed.

```
<< Developer`

PackedArrayQ /@ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, Range[4]}
(* {False, True} *)
```

There is a bug, where if the *sublists* in the array fed to `TreeForm` are packed, then the function doesn't behave properly:

```
TreeForm /@ {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {Range[4]}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a workaround you can first search for any packed arrays, unpack them, and then feed the result to `TreeForm`

```
treeForm[arr_] := 
 TreeForm[arr /. {x_?PackedArrayQ :> FromPackedArray[x]}]

treeForm /@ {{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {Range[4]}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, if you haven't loaded the `Developer` package, you can use this:

```
treeForm[arr_] := 
 TreeForm[arr /. {x_?Developer`PackedArrayQ :> 
     Developer`FromPackedArray[x]}]
```